# Large XML Files in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, database, ssms

I tried to import a big XML File in SSMS,
but I encounter this problem.

> 'INSXMLII.XML' is too large to open with XML editor. The maximum file
>   size is '10' MB. Please update the registry key
>   'HKCU\Software\Microsoft\SQL Server Management
>   Studio\18.0_IsoShell_Config\XmlEditor\MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService'
>   to change the maximum size.

I used method to fix:
Navigate to:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>   18\Common7\IDE"

Edit the "Microsoft.XmlEditor.pkgdef" file at approximately line number 322:

Change the line:

> "MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService"="10"

To:

> "MaxFileSizeSupportedByLanguageService"="99999999999"

Restart SSMS.

However, it encountered this problem:

> "Access to the path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server
>   Management Studio
>   18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Platform\Shell\Microsoft.XmlEditor.pkgdef"

Any thoughts? I have totally no ideas~
Many thanks

Comment: 99999999999 may too too big. Try something like 100 (you forgot to mention the actual size of the file).

Comment: My thought is that this is not what SSMS was made for. If the XML is less than 2GB you could import it into a XML column and query it using T-SQL instead.

Comment: I usually parse files in a programming language like c# or vb.net and then put data into database.

Comment: how do you "import"? SSMS is not made to operate on large files, use `sqlcmd` instead.

Comment: @jasonroy7dct, please edit your post and elaborate on "...I tried to import a big XML File in SSMS..." and share your T-SQL. You shared your error, but we don't know what you tried to do, and what caused the error.

Comment: Hi all, I solved it after change the "security" of file to full control and it help.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you case use this C# code to read all content:

```cs
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("..YOUR QUERY..", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var cellStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                using (var dataReader = await sqlCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync())
                {
                    while (dataReader.Read()) cellStringBuilder.Append(dataReader.GetString(0));
                }

                // Do something with cellStringBuilder.ToString()...
            }
```